# Can't create instance of generated type: No parameterless constructor defined for this object

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, reflection.emit

I'm generating new dynamic type and wan't to create it's instance. But when actually create instantiation code, it's fails with exception: `No parameterless constructor defined for this object.`

My code is the following:

```
AssemblyBuilder aBuilder = AssemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicAssembly(new AssemblyName("dfsdfsdf"), AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run);
ModuleBuilder mBuilder = aBuilder.DefineDynamicModule("dsadsadasdasda");
TypeBuilder typeBlank = mBuilder.DefineType("dasvvvvvvvv", TypeAttributes.Class | TypeAttributes.Public);
ConstructorBuilder cb = typeBlank.DefineDefaultConstructor(MethodAttributes.Public);
Type t = cb.GetType();
var item = Activator.CreateInstance(t);  // <--- Error appear in this line.
```

What is wrong there?

Comment: Which line exactly this error appears?

Comment: have you tried defining a parameterless constructor? :O

Comment: Yes, I tryed. The same story. However I think default constuctor and parameterless one is more or less the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're trying to create an instance of `ConstructorBuilder`, not your generated class.

I think you want:

```
...
ConstructorBuilder cb = typeBlank.DefineDefaultConstructor(MethodAttributes.Public);
Type t = typeBlank.CreateType();
var item = Activator.CreateInstance(t);
```

Note that a parameterless default constructor is created by default; you don't need to create one except in the following circumstances:

(From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.typebuilder.definedefaultconstructor(v=vs.110).aspx)):

> Because the default constructor is automatically defined, it is
>   necessary to call this method only in the following situations:
>
> - You have defined another constructor and you also want a default constructor that simply calls the base class constructor.
> - You want to set the attributes on the default constructor to something other  than `PrivateScope`, `Public`, `HideBySig`, `SpecialName`,
>     and `RTSpecialName`.

Comment: Thanks, yes, that's correct. Just trying a ot of things and miss that GetType() and CreateType() return different results. Btw, one more question - maybe you just know the answer, because I wasn't able to find it. There is dynamic assembly associated with this type. If I don't have assemblyBuilder instance for those assembly, is there a chance to  add more types in it in future somehowe? I need to generate fake types in to assembly for testingpourposes and it's important for me to be able add/remove them dynamically.

Comment: @silent_coder If you have another question, you should *ask a new question*.